# Azure Streaming Analytics job not connecting to Event Hub input

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

When I use the `Process Data` feature within my event hub, I am able to develop a query, see data and get results. However, when I click `Deploy Query` the query view cannot connect to my event hub and fails with:

```
Unable to build a valid connection string with the given parameters. Error message: Please make sure either all or none of the following arguments are defined: 'SharedAccessKeyName, SharedAccessSecret'. Parameter name: SharedAccessKeyName, SharedAccessSecret
```

[image]

This also happens when I go the other direction and create streaming analytics job from scratch. Even while [following this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/process-data-azure-stream-analytics?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstream-analytics%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json) I get the same error.

Just to be clear, the analytics job works correctly when running but I am not able to run queries against sample data so it's difficult to make adjustments.

Comment: can you please provide detailed steps, and it's better to provide some screenshots as well. I just tried to deploy query, it's ok at my side.

Comment: @IvanYang - I just added a screenshot. For detailed recreation steps, following the tutorial I linked is the best way to recreate how I got there. Thanks!

Comment: From the screenshot, I see the there is a warning after the Inputs, can you please nav to the Inputs -> to check if you have provided the event hub policy name and policy key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to follow up on this, I was able to work with @Ajeta from the Streaming Analytics product team directly and they identified it as a configuration issue on their side.

After an update it started working with no changed on my side.

Answer (score 0):

@tyler When you go to Overview of your Event Hub (from the left pane), do you see any incoming events?